# Using perlin noise as a procedural voxel heightmap without a texture atlas in Unity

Tags: unity, c#, procedural-generation, voxels, perlin-noise

I was creating a heightmap for my procedural voxel world in Unity using 2D perlin noise. I don't want to use anything from a texture atlas, a brown Unity material is good enough for me. The issue is that I cannot seem to replace what would be "air blocks" by deleting voxels in the grid above a certain height threshold.

I have a function to check whether or not a voxel is above the heightmap, but when I play the scene I'm still left with large cube shaped chunks. Any idea why this isn't working? Thanks in advance and let me know if additional information is needed.

```
    bool CheckVoxel(Vector3 pos)
    {

        int x = Mathf.FloorToInt(pos.x);
        int y = Mathf.FloorToInt(pos.y);
        int z = Mathf.FloorToInt(pos.z);
        int terrainHeight = Mathf.FloorToInt(Noise.Get2DPerlin(new Vector2(pos.x, pos.z), 1.0f, 0.5f)) + 50;

        // If position is outside of this chunk...
        if (x < 0 || x > VoxelData.ChunkWidth - 1 || y < 0 || y > VoxelData.ChunkHeight - 1 || z < 0 || z > VoxelData.ChunkWidth - 1)
            return false;
        // If position is above the height map position...
        else if (y > terrainHeight)
            return false;
        else return true;
    }
    //now just check voxels and create our mesh
    void AddVoxelDataToChunk(Vector3 pos)
    {

        for (int p = 0; p < 6; p++)
        {

            if (!CheckVoxel(pos + VoxelData.faceChecks[p]))
            {               

                vertices.Add(pos + VoxelData.voxelVerts[VoxelData.voxelTris[p, 0]]);
                vertices.Add(pos + VoxelData.voxelVerts[VoxelData.voxelTris[p, 1]]);
                vertices.Add(pos + VoxelData.voxelVerts[VoxelData.voxelTris[p, 2]]);
                vertices.Add(pos + VoxelData.voxelVerts[VoxelData.voxelTris[p, 3]]);


                triangles.Add(vertexIndex);
                triangles.Add(vertexIndex + 1);
                triangles.Add(vertexIndex + 2);
                triangles.Add(vertexIndex + 2);
                triangles.Add(vertexIndex + 1);
                triangles.Add(vertexIndex + 3);
                vertexIndex += 4;

            }
        }

    }

    public void CreateMesh()
    {

        Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
        mesh.vertices = vertices.ToArray();
        mesh.triangles = triangles.ToArray();
        mesh.uv = uvs.ToArray();

        mesh.RecalculateNormals();

        meshFilter.mesh = mesh;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a bad question. I forgot a reference to my chunk height in the noise function, so it was just setting y to be between 0 and 1 until i multipled by chunk height.